# Get podspec from server outside repo via http / Error

Tags: ios, git, cocoapods, podspec

I want to get podspec via http outside repository:

ex: pod 'MySdk', :podspec => 'https://example.com/MySdk.podspec'

but i got this error:

Any one have idea . thx

`` Pod::Downloader::Http::UnsupportedFileTypeError - Unsupported file type: 
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-downloader-1.1.3/lib/cocoapods-downloader/http.rb:88:in `filename_with_type'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-downloader-1.1.3/lib/cocoapods-downloader/http.rb:24:in `download!'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-downloader-1.1.3/lib/cocoapods-downloader/base.rb:82:in `block in download'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.3.1/lib/cocoapods/downloader.rb:157:in `block in ui_action'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.3.1/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.3.1/lib/cocoapods/downloader.rb:156:in `ui_action'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-downloader-1.1.3/lib/cocoapods-downloader/base.rb:80:in `download'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.3.1/lib/cocoapods/downloader.rb:108:in `download_source'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.3.1/lib/cocoapods/downloader.rb:75:in `download_request'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.3.1/lib/cocoapods/downloader/cache.rb:171:in `download'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.3.1/lib/cocoapods/downloader/cache.rb:154:in `block in uncached_pod'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.3.1/lib/cocoapods/downloader/cache.rb:181:in `in_tmpdir'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.3.1/lib/cocoapods/downloader/cache.rb:153:in `uncached_pod'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.3.1/lib/cocoapods/downloader/cache.rb:33:in `download_pod'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.3.1/lib/cocoapods/downloader.rb:42:in `download'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.3.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/pod_source_installer.rb:120:in `download_source'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.3.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/pod_source_installer.rb:60:in `install!'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.3.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:364:in `install_source_of_pod'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.3.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:329:in `block (2 levels) in install_pod_sources'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.3.1/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:85:in `titled_section'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.3.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:328:in `block in install_pod_sources'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.3.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:320:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.3.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:320:in `install_pod_sources'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.3.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:163:in `block in download_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.3.1/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.3.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:161:in `download_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.3.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:117:in `install!'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.3.1/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:41:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/claide-1.0.2/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.3.1/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.3.1/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/pod:22:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/pod:22:in `<main>' ``

Comment: I got the answer and it work fine. Juste make zip file , inside the file i have the podspec ans source

Answer (score 0):

Zip file will solve the pb.

See: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cocoapods/Sq9c59U7Hro